# Graphics cards - blue tint flashing in some games?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have recently come accross a problem (as of yesterday) in my PC where in some games, the screen becomes tinted blue.

There are no graphical artifacts being displayed with this.

The blue tint I see on my screen is as though someone have maxed the Blue balance in RGB. I can still play games ok however they are just tinted blue.

Games that are affected by this are:

1. ArmA 2
2. GTA 4

**THESE GAMES WERE OK AS OF SUNDAY AFAIK**

Games that I have tried which are not affected by this:

1. Battlefield 2
2. Battlefield 3
3. The Elder Scrolls Skyrim
4. Modern Warfare 2

This makes the situation more puzzling as why are some games affected and others not.

My System Specs:

> - AMD Athlon X2 6400+ (3.2ghz)
> - 4GB PC2 6400
> - 2 * 500 Seagate
> - 2 * 1gb Gainward Bliss 8800GT
> - Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

My driver version from **NVIDIA is 285.36** .

SLI is enabled on both cards.

Temperatures on cards after playing Elder Scrolls Skyrim were:

- Card 1 - **59 degrees** centigrade
- Card 2 - **37 degrees** centigrade

This makes me suspicious as why is one of the cards cooler than the other?

Any suggestions what I should do to remedy this situation.

The blue tint only happens when playing certain games. When I go back to Windows it is normal.

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: Try re-seating the SLI bridge and video connectors (esp if VGA). Some drivers had bugs that caused issues like this but it was in reference to ATI drivers.

Comment: @Brian  Mine is DVI to HDMI but thanks, I will reseat the SLI bridge, should I reseat the cards in  PCI slots also?

Comment: "Temperatures on cards after playing"   What about during? There's no way your GPU stays at 37 degrees under load.  Also, in SLI configuration large temperature differences are common (the second GPU really impedes the flow of heat throughout the case).